# IBM Mobilefirst 7.1 PushNotifications: Unable to retrieve notification text from background to foreground

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

We have integrated Tag Based and Broadcast notifications in our MobileFirst app. We are able to send the notifications when the app is open and user is able to see the notification text. But when the user kills the app and notification arrives in notification panel: user is able to click on notification and it opens the app but it doesn't shows the notification text.

Please find the code below:

```
/* TagBased and Broadcast Notification Code Start */
var chkHolder;
function suborunsub(chkbxFlag){
console.log('The value of checkbox flag is:'+chkbxFlag);
var checkBox;
if(chkbxFlag=='TG1') {
    chkHolder = "TAG1";
    checkBox = document.getElementById("SUBTG1").checked;
    console.log('The checkbox value is:'+checkBox);
    if(checkBox) {
        subscribeToNotifTag('TAG1');
    } else {
        unsubscribeFromNotifTag('TAG1');
    }
} else if(chkbxFlag=='TG2') {
    chkHolder = "TAG 2";
    checkBox = document.getElementById("SUBTG2").checked;
    console.log('The checkbox value is:'+checkBox);
    if(checkBox) {

        subscribeToNotifTag('TAG2');
    } else {
        unsubscribeFromNotifTag('TAG2');
    }
} 
//---------------------------- Check if push support is available-----------
function isPushSupported() {
var isSupported = false;
if (WL.Client.Push){
    isSupported = WL.Client.Push.isPushSupported();
}   
WL.SimpleDialog.show("Alert", JSON.stringify(isSupported), [ {
    text : 'Close',
    handler : function() {}
  }
]);
}
// --------------------------------- Subscribe to tag --------------------

function subscribeToNotifTag(nTag) {
  WL.Client.Push.subscribeTag(nTag, {
        onSuccess: subscribeTagSuccess,
        onFailure: subscribeTagFailure
    });
}

function subscribeTagSuccess() {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Alert", "Subscribed to : "+chkHolder, [ {
    text : 'Close',
    handler : function() {}
  }
  ]);
}

function subscribeTagFailure() {
WL.SimpleDialog.show("Alert", "Failed to subscribe : "+chkHolder, [ {
    text : 'Close',
    handler : function() {}
  }
  ]);
}

// ------------------------------- Unsubscribe from tag --------------------

function unsubscribeFromNotifTag(nTag) {
WL.Client.Push.unsubscribeTag(nTag, {
        onSuccess: unsubscribeTagSuccess,
        onFailure: unsubscribeTagFailure
    });
}
function unsubscribeTagSuccess() {
WL.SimpleDialog.show("Alert", "Unsubscribed to : "+chkHolder, [ {
    text : 'Close',
    handler : function() {}
  }
  ]);
}

function unsubscribeTagFailure() {
WL.SimpleDialog.show("Alert", "Failed to unsubscribe : "+chkHolder, [ {
    text : 'Close',
    handler : function() {}
  }
  ]);
}

//------------------------------- Handle received notification -----------
WL.Client.Push.onMessage = function (props) {
if(WL.StaticAppProps.ENVIRONMENT=='iphone') {
WL.SimpleDialog.show("Alert", ""  + JSON.stringify(props.alert.body), [ {
    text : 'Close',
    handler : function() {}
}]);
}else if(WL.StaticAppProps.ENVIRONMENT=='android') {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Alert", ""  + JSON.stringify(props.alert), [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {}
    }]);
    }
};
/* TagBased and Broadcast Notification Code End */
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.myAPP" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="8.2">  
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>  
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="false"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>  
<!-- Push permissions -->  
<permission android:name="com.myAPP.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.myAPP.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>  
<application android:label="@string/app_name"  android:icon="@drawable/icon"> 
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBHvtzEPwG4DYTG9Zsvijz9mRIC53ehleU"/>  
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>  
    <activity android:name=".myAPP" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.myAPP.myAPP.NOTIFICATION"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>  
    <activity android:name=".MGMapFragment" android:theme="@style/Theme.MGMapTheme"/>  
    <activity android:name=".MGMultiMapFragment" android:theme="@style/Theme.MGMapTheme"/>  
    <activity android:name=".MGPickerMapFragment" android:theme="@style/Theme.MGPckrTheme"/>  
    <!-- Preference Activity  -->  
    <activity android:name="com.worklight.common.WLSettingActivity" android:label="Worklight Settings"/>  
    <!-- UI Activity for displaying native dialogs  -->  
    <activity android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.ui.UIActivity"/>  
    <!-- Push service  -->  
    <!-- In order to use the c2dm library, an application must declare a class with the name C2DMReceiver, in its own package, extending com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver 
        It must also include this section in the manifest, replacing "com.google.android.apps.chrometophone" with its package name. -->  
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>  
    <service android:name=".ForegroundService"/>  
    <!-- Only google service can send data messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->  
    <receiver android:name="com.worklight.androidgap.push.WLBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> 
        <!-- Receive the actual message -->  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>  
            <category android:name="com.myAPP"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <!-- Receive the registration id -->  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>  
            <category android:name="com.myAPP"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver> 
   </application> 
 </manifest>
```

Comment: Whether the app is closed or open, it reaches the same code path in the main.js file; so the problem is a setup problem. Likely in AndroidManifest.xml - can you add it? Did you change it in any way? Strings? Names?

Comment: App is closed and we havent changed any strings or names in manifest file.

Comment: Mention your exact build number. Did you check with the sample app? Is it not working as well?

Comment: Build Number: 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201512191535. I have tried on sample app which worked fine. Even I have compared the both android manifest.xml files and there is no difference except some of additional activities.

Comment: Remove the "WL.StaticAppProps.ENVIRONMENT" condition check in your code and then try.

Comment: I have tried using the default code which comes with sample app and it worked fine. But the reason behind using this "WL.StaticAppProps.ENVIRONMENT" is that we want to  show only the notification text to the users. Is there any best way to show just the notification text to the users?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using the default code which comes with sample app and it worked fine. But the reason behind using this "WL.StaticAppProps.ENVIRONMENT" is that we want to show only the notification text to the users. Is there any best way to show just the notification text to the users?

What do you mean "just the notification text"? How is this different from the default notification? The sample app shows how you can access the notification object and display the payload and props. Seperately.

```
function pushNotificationReceived(props, payload) {

    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Push Notifications", "Provider notification data: " + JSON.stringify(props), [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {
            WL.SimpleDialog.show("Push Notifications", "Application notification data: " + JSON.stringify(payload), [ {
                text : 'Close',
                handler : function() {}
              }]);      
        }
    }]);
}
```

Comment: When we use "+ JSON.stringify(props)"  it send the notification as "Provider notification data: {"alert":test, "badge":1,"sound":null,"priority":0}". so in this we just want to show the "alert":test to the users. so that's where we customized it to "+ JSON.stringify(props.alert)".